# Can't acquire DHCP with WPA2 Enterprise

Tags: macos, network, wifi, enterprise

I have a user with a MacBook Pro (late 2013) running OS X 10.10.5 "Yosemite" that can't acquire a DHCP address from our corporate Wi-Fi. It's a WPA2 Enterprise network with Meraki on the back end. From the Meraki tools I can see him authenticate successfully but just won't accept an IP.

It's worth nothing that we have a dozen other Macs (iMacs, MBPs, Mac Minis) all connected without issue. iPhones, Android, and Windows 7/8 all connect to the same network without issue as well.

Outside of an answer, are there some tools I can use to troubleshoot this better?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. I wanted to post a solution in case anybody else sees this. There was a corrupted lease in our DHCP server that this Mac kept trying to request. As a result, the two (DHCP server & Mac) went into a loop until timeout.

Fixing the DHCP database the Mac acquired an address with no issues.

Comment: i know it's been over 3 years since you posted this, but i'm hoping you might remember how you tested that DHCP was handing out a corrupt lease? Was there a log on either end that you were reviewing?

Comment: I remember speaking with Meraki support and we were looking through debug logs in the dashboard itself. We compared the traces to healthy requests and could see that the Mac was abnormal. I think I searched our server for the MAC address or maybe deleted leases randomly, but I know when I did the Mac worked just fine.